# Yii2: Не могу осуществить миграции RBAC (You should configure “authManager”…)

Tags: yii2, composer

Я устанавливаю yii2-rbac согласно этой страницы сайта: https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac/blob/master/docs/installation.md. Я делаю это во второй раз. Первый раз, когда я это сделал, я написал в файле config / web.php:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium \ user \ Module',
    ],
    // 'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacWebModule',
    'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacConsoleModule',
],
```

Я не знал, что 'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacConsoleModule' нужно писать в console.php (не в web.php).

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii \ rbac \ DbManager',
    // 'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
],
```

`Этот код, который я написал в обоих конфигурационных файлах: web.php и console.php, но в web.php я написал 'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacConsoleModule' и в console.php Я его не написал , но все работало: yii2-rbac был установлен успешно. И все транзакции прошли успешно. Но 'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacConsoleModule' в web.php кажется мне неправильным. Это не веб-модуль, это консольный модуль. Затем у меня есть отменённые транзакции (migrate / down), и я вообще удалил rbac, удалив из обявления composer.json «dektrium / yii2-rbac»: «1.0.0-alpha@dev». Все было удалено. Затем я начал устанавливать rbac второй раз. После установки с помощью composer я написал в web.php:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium \ user \ Module',
    ],
    'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacWebModule',
    // 'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacConsoleModule',
],
```

и в console.php Я писал:

```
'modules' => [

    'rbac' => 'dektrium \ rbac \ RbacConsoleModule',

],
```

Сайт на yii2 не работает после этого. Я изменил в web.php «... RbacConsoleModule». Сайт работает. Почему не работает с RbacWebModule? Затем я попытался применить транзакции, которые я откатил раньше, но вызвало ошибку: `у вас неправильная конфигурация authManager.`

Comment: Я задал этот же вопрос по-английски в английской версии сайта. С помощью гугл переводчика я всё тупо перевёл, исправил некоторые ошибки перевода и вставил сюда в русскую версию. Вот ссылка на английскую версию: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632453/installing-yii2-rbac-error-you-have-wrong-authmanager-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему. Надо было вставить секцию authManager

```
'authManager' => [
'class' => 'yii \ rbac \ DbManager',
// 'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
```

],

в раздел modules, а не componenets